Headphones not detected anymore
After working fine for multiple years, suddenly it seems like my headphones (mini-jack) are not detected any more by my computer.
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
It feels like some setting has changed without me knowing it, as the headphones worked perfectly until a couple of days ago and still do so with other input devices.
When I play audio and plug in the head phones, the audio continues to go through the thinkpad speakers (no audio on headphones) where it previously switch automatically from speakers to headphones. I'm guessing the headphones or jack input is not detected as I also cannot switch to the headphones manually in the sound settings. They are not shown as an option.
Any and all suggestions are very welcome.
Many thanks!

really sounds (no pun intended) like a hardware issue to me. Have you another device (speakers or the like) you can use to cross check or perhaps a live usb session with a different iso/Linux distro ?

Thanks for the suggestion graham.  I've plugged in my external speakers but they are also not detected. The speakers do work on other devices. I'm afraid to say that I don't know what a live usb session with a different iso/linux distro means but if it's a hardware problem, would that mean some physical part of the computer has stopped working?

you might find create a bootable USB useful in that case. It allows you to have a live session of a distro without actually installing it.
